# How does ory/hydra compared to Okta and Auth0?

Tags: single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, okta, idp

Is ORY/Hydra pretty much the same thing as Okta and Auth0 expect that Hydra is open-source and has limited support compared to the later ones?

Comment: I'd say that it's the combination of Ory Kratos and Ory Hydra that can compare to Auth0.